# C++ Create a static class to store pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, static, sdl-2

I'm trying to learn my way around C++ by making a simple game/engine with SDL2. Currently I'm having some issues trying to make a static class.

I think the easiest way is to just describe what I want to achieve:

- I want to be able to make a class (called Pointer) which will store pointers to different crucial objects like the window and the renderer.
- I want to set these values to the Pointer class(private variables), from my main *.cpp file after I have created and initialized the window/renderer.
- Then I want to be able to use this class to access those objects through getter functions from wherever I might be in the program, but
- I want them to be static, so that I can access the original values, and not initialize new empty ones.

I hope this was somewhat understandable.

Comment: What is preventing you from moving forward with this? Do you not know the syntax for declaring a class with static members or getters a setters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(`Pointer` is a *terrible* class name.)

You want a class such that only one instance can exist at a time, and it is accessible to any code that is aware of the class. The solution is **the Singleton Pattern**. It is a badly overused pattern (novices like to use it as a substitute for global variables) but this is exactly the kind of thing it's good for.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into that. I'm not going to overuse it, just trying to avoid nested function parameter passes in the future. And btw, _Pointer_ was a made up name for the examples sake :)

Comment: sounds like a terrible solution :-) Try to avoid global variables (singletons as well) at all costs!

Comment: @dau_sama: You know of a better solution? I await your Answer with bated breath.

Comment: unfortunately the question is not very clear. One could have a manager class that handles lifetime of some obejcts, and pass the class around as a reference. You can then access your resources from that proxy class. There is no need of static members anywhere, and it gets easier to unit test as well.

Comment: Everywhere I go, there are people saying this is bad, so I got that. But be aware that I'm still not comfortable with C++'s advanced side. Right now I just need things to work, then I can start focus on making it perfect down the road ;)

Comment: @dau_sama: "at all costs" is most certainly wrong. Global variables have their place, like goto.

Comment: Speaking of how much you guys love the Singleton Pattern, I got one Mr. _unresolved external symbol_ error in there. Seems like it's complaining about line 30. Anyone care to take a look? -> http://pastebin.com/CDzmzEty - would be much appreaciated. :)

Comment: @DietrichEpp that's for sure, however I prefer to teach younger minds that a singleton has to be an exception, not the norm

Comment: @coco4l you have to define the type, outside of the class, since it's not bound to the object itself. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static

Now, just get rid of all that and write it as follows:
`Wrapper& AccessWrapper::getInstance() { static Wrapper w; return w; }`

You may also need to separate the Singleton manager from the actual object that does the job.
Please not that static initialization is now guaranteed to be thread safe since `C++11`

Comment: @dau_sama: Yes, I agree completely, that's exactly why it's important to avoid absolutes like "at all costs".

Comment: @DietrichEpp: Not very absolute; went from *"avoid at all costs!"* to *"exception, not the norm"* to *"write it as follows"* in the course of three hours.

Comment: @dau_sama To be honest, _"just get rid of all that"_ and _"write it as follow: (code)"_, only confused me. After a long while I read I should add `AccessWrapper* AccessWrapper::m_access;` in the .cpp file, which solved it. Thanks guys!

Comment: @coco4l fact is, you don't need to `new` that object at all. That is bad `C++` practice

Comment: @dau_sama `m_access = new AccessWrapper();`changed to `m_access = &AccessWrapper();` - Thx.